# reducing commands with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm just interested if it's possible to reduce this commands to one line without `&&`?

```
find /backup/daily.1/var/www/ -iname "*.jpg" -type f >> ~/backuppath.txt
sed 's|/backup/daily.1||g' ~/backuppath.txt > ~/wwwpath.txt
paste -d " " ~/backuppath.txt ~/wwwpath.txt > ~/files.txt
while read line; do cp $line; done < ~/files.txt
```

Comment: This code is craziness.  If all you're trying to do is backup the jpegs in a certain directory and preserve the directory structure, there are better ways.

Comment: Shure ;) That's a negative example. In this case i'd use it to recover all the jpg's from the backup directory. The tricky point is to cut the `/backup/daily.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't write it on one line, but you can do without the intermediate files:

```
find /backup/daily.1/var/www/ -iname "*.jpg" -type f |
sed 's%/backup/daily.1\(.*\)%cp & \1%' |
sh -x
```

The `sed` command splits the file names into two components, the `/backup/daily.1` prefix and 'the rest', and replaces that with the complete copy command copying the original name to the name without the prefix.  The output of `sed` is fed to the shell as a script.

This should work fine unless there's a file name that contains shell metacharacters, spaces or newlines.  You can improve the resiliency if there won't be newlines or single quotes in the file names with:

```
find /backup/daily.1/var/www/ -iname "*.jpg" -type f |
sed "s%/backup/daily.1\(.*\)%cp '&' '\1'%" |
sh -x
```

This wraps each filename in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This does not deal with filenames with spaces.  (This is not important, I merely
state this to preempt the inevitable comments.)

```
find /backup/daily.1/var/www/ -iname "*.jpg" -type f |
while read name; do cp $name ${name#/backup/daily.1}; done
```

You can also just do:

```
find /backup/daily.1/var/www/ -iname "*.jpg" \
    -type f -exec sh -c 'cp "$0" "${0#/backup/daily.1}"' {} \;
```

which handles unusual filename well.

Comment: The error can be circumvented by using proper escaping : `cp $name ${name/\/backup\/daily.0}`

Comment: +1 for the only simple, robust solution (the -exec one)! The alternative would be `find ... -print0 | xargs -0...`

Answer (score 0):

```
find /backup/daily.1/var/www/ -iname "*.jpg" -type f \
 | sed 's|^/backup/daily\.1\(.*\)$|\0 \1|' \
 | ( while read origin dest; do cp "$origin" "$dest"; done)
```

In the `sed` expression :

- `\0` is replaced by the matched string, which is the whole line is this case
- `\1` is replaced by the subpattern match `\(.*\)`, that is everything from after `/backup/daily.1` up to the end of the line